# Trabajar service-worker.js con React Router

Tags: reactjs, firebase, pwa, service-workers

Cordial saludo.

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación en ReactJS la cual quiero convertir en una PWA.

He agregado el service worker con todos sus métodos para poder realizar lo que necesito, además de agregar push notifications a través de Firebase.

El problema radica en que la aplicación no reconoce los scripts que estoy manejando con Firebase junto con el service-worker dando el siguiente error en Firefox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mirando en otro navegador, en este caso Chrome el error es más detallado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Validando el problema ocurre porque los scripts están entrando en conflicto con la forma en que estoy declarando las rutas en la aplicación por medio de React Router, a continuación muestro como tengo declaradas las rutas (tanto publicas como privadas):

```
const PublicRoute = () => {

return (
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/recovery/:token">
             <Recovery />
           </Route>
           <Route exact path="/forgot">
            <Forgot />
           </Route>
           <Route exact path="/login">
             <Login />
           </Route>
           <Redirect to='/login' />
        </Switch>
     );  
 }

const PrivateRoute = () => {

return (
     <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/">
            <Dashboard />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/users">
            <Users />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/profile">
            <Profile />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/type-medition">
            <TypeMedition />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/sensors">
            <Sensors />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/meditions">
            <Meditions />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/units">
            <Units />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/sites">
            <Sites />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/dashboards">
            <DashboardCrud />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/category-sites">
            <CategorySites />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/form/:seccion">
            <Form />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/form/:seccion/:id">
             <Form />
         </Route>
         <Route path="*">
             <NotMatch />
         </Route>
      </Switch>
   );      
 }
```

Entonces, cualquier enlace o recurso que vaya por algo que no está declarado en las rutas va o devolverme al login en el caso de las rutas públicas, o a un componente not found creado para el caso de las privadas, es la razón por la que no soporta el tipo de formato del service-worker:

> The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

Al revisar las rutas de los scripts efectivamente redirige a un html, este caso el NotFound.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de poder ejecutar los scripts sin que eso afecte las rutas ya establecidas del react-router, o dentro de la misma librería declarar alguna regla que haga la excepción a esos scripts?

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo una inspección más minuciosa, se tuvo que agregar a la carpeta public, un archivo llamado firebase-messaging-sw.js vacío y con esto se resuelve el error, esto ocurre porque las rutas basadas en front-end no reconocen los recursos a nivel del src, porque la ruta evalúa desde el index.html de la aplicación.

De la misma forma se agregó el archivo service-worker.js también en public, con esto ya firebase y el navegador pueden hacer el manejo de caché que necesita la pwa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que la respuesta sirva, o se tenga una manera más óptima de resolver el problema.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.